# Why does my for loop not make each marker unique in my google maps activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to open a new activity when a user clicks on the window of a marker.

Now I am doing everything correctly it seems and it even works but only for one single shop, it brings all the information from that single shop and places it in every marker every time a user clicks it.

I am wondering why this is happening and why is my `shop object` not being unique to each marker since its inside of a for loop.

When I open any window from any marker it takes me to the same shop details which in my case is "Starbucks". Why is that?

Here is the code:

```
  public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {


    CollectionReference mapRef = fStore.collection("Shops");
    Query mapQuery = mapRef;
    mapRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            for(final QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){

                final  Shop shop = documentSnapshot.toObject(Shop.class);

                String Lat = shop.getLatitude();
                String Long = shop.getLongitude();

                float latitude = Float.parseFloat(Lat);
                float longitude = Float.parseFloat(Long);

                final LatLng shopLoc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


              final Marker markers = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(shopLoc)
                        .title(""+shop.getName())
                        .snippet(shop.getShopPID()));

              googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                      Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
                      i.putExtra("shopModel",shop);
                      startActivity(i);
                  }
              });

              



            }
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Because whenever you set new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener, it overrides the old one. so only the last one is set! And it copies object of shop in itself. So it opens the last item in for loop for all markers.

Comment: @abbasoveissi okay i understand now. is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it!!!

i did some research and there were other stackoverflow answers to this question. i just took out the oninfoclick outside the for loop and did as follows:

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(shopLoc)
                        .title(""+shop.getName()).snippet("Click to view shops information"));
              marker.setTag(shop);
```

and then outside the for loop i did this:

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
                Shop shop2 = (Shop) marker.getTag();
                i.putExtra("shopModel",shop2);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```